# "typename vector<T>::iterator" does not recognized by compiler

Tags: c++, templates, typename

Now I have a template method like this:

```
template<typename T>
void f(typename vector<T>::iterator it)
{
//implemenation
...
}

int main()
{
vector<int> v;
//initialization of v;
...

f(v.begin());

return 0;
}
```

But when I compile as "g++ THIS_FILE -o TARGET_RUNNABLE", the compile says

```
 no matching function for call to ‘f(std::vector<int>::iterator)’
 template argument deduction/substitution failed:
 couldn't deduce template parameter ‘T’
```

I do realize to add keyword **"typename"** before vector::iterator. But it is still wrong. Does anybody know how to fix this problem?

Comment: You can't deduce things like that.

Comment: You cannot deduce the container type from an iterator type portably. Typically, one would write the function like `template<typename It> void f(It it);` (and then still use `f(v.begin())`). If you do need the container type, you have to pass another argument (`template<class Cont, class It> void f(Cont&, It);`) or explicitly specify a template argument `template<class Cont, class It> void f(It); f<std::vector<int>>(v.begin());`).

Answer (score 2):

Your function takes an iterator, but you are trying to pass a vector. You might have meant `f(v.begin())` or something like that.

Also, as @chris notes, `T` is in a non-deducible context. It would have to be provided explicitly, as in `f<int>(v.begin());`

Comment: sry, this is a mistype. it is f(v.begin()) in the question

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that Template Argument Deduction works on about 20 different forms, but not the form `typename Foo<T>::Bar`. The reason is that there are infinitely many `Foo`s, and each of them could have a nested type `Bar` which matches yours. The compiler can't search all of them.

A good example of such a problem is `std::vector<T>::const_iterator` versus `std::vector<const T>::const_iterator`, which might very well be the same type.

It's therefore called a *non-deduced context*. You have to be explicit which template you want .

Comment: This actually does not answer the question (i.e. "how to fix?")

Answer (score 1):

One way to fix the compiler error is to be explicit about the template parameter.

```
f<int>(v.begin());
```

Answer (score 0):

You passed `v` which is `vector<int>` to function `f`. You should pass iterator to `f`.

Just redesign your template function to

```
template<typename Iterator>
void f(Iterator it)
{ 
   // manipulate iterator it
}
```

then you could call

```
vector<int> v;

f(v.begin());
```

Comment: I am sry this is a mistype in my question. In fact it is really f(v.begin()) but does not work.